# Protractor test cases are failing on Jenkins server but they pass on Local machine: TimeoutError at selenuim server

Tags: jenkins, protractor

We have e2e test integrated with Jenkins system. When I execute this script in my local machine, test script is running fine but when I run the same on Jenkins server, test script will fail with below message

```
 TimeoutError: Wait timed out after 25008ms
  at /datas/jenkins/workspace/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:2201:17
  at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
  at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

To launch to e2e test, I run at first:

webdriver-manager update

Then I run the xvfb

xvfb-run -a webdriver-manager start --seleniumPort 4445

and finally i run the test with protractor

I share with you my protractor.conf.js file:

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 20000,

    specs: [
        './e2e/account/**/*.spec.ts',
        /* jhipster-needle-add-protractor-tests - JHipster will add protractors tests here */
    ],

    capabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions: {
            args: [ "--headless", "--no-sandbox" ,"--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--window-size=800x600"],
            binary: '/usr/bin/google-chrome'

        }
    },
    directConnect: true,

    baseUrl: 'https://sso.com',

    framework: 'mocha',

    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,

    mochaOpts: {
        reporter: 'spec',
        slow: 3000,
        ui: 'bdd',
        timeout: 720000
    },

    beforeLaunch: function() {
        require('ts-node').register({
            project: 'tsconfig.e2e.json'
        });
    },

    onPrepare: function() {
        browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);
        // Disable animations
        // @ts-ignore
        browser.executeScript('document.body.className += " notransition";');
        const chai = require('chai');
        const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');
        chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
        const chaiString = require('chai-string');
        chai.use(chaiString);
        // @ts-ignore
        global.chai = chai;
    },

    useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
};
```

I am looking for ideas about the cause.

Update: I execute the same command on a docker container. I get the same error at jenkins. I can't figure out the difference between them

Comment: If I had this problem I would install https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-video-reporter and looked at what actually happens. More precisely, I would want to see if timeout happens in the beginning of tests, or it happens at certain step. In first case the problem is in framework, in other one, problem with your specs

Comment: Firstly, you set `directConnect: true`, thus no need to run `webdriver-manager start`, secondly you set headless model by `--headless` in `chromeOptions.args`, thus `browser.driver.manage().window().setSize(1280, 1024);` in onPrepare() is unnecessary.  you should set window size by `--window-size` in  `chromeOptions.args`.  Fix the two issues and run again.

Comment: @yong you have a point. I do what you have suggested, but nothing changed

Comment: @SergeyPleshakov if I change "await" key by "then (=>{})", the test passes. This is another issue. I will follow your advice to see what's going on.

Comment: Did you use global protractor to execute your cases in Jenkins?  `async/await` only start works at a specific protractor version and higher.  And `SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false`  is deprecated since one protractor version and you have to use `async/await` to manage controlflow

Comment: I use script "npm run e2e" where e2e is "protractor protractor.conf.js" on the package.json. For protractor I use v5.4.2. SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false is by default false. It's just to be sure.

Comment: I identify the problem. I opened another question. It's related to self ssl certification. Can you please give a look ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59630672/protractor-self-signed-ssl-headless-test-e2e-dont-pass